# sqlite3_step is returning error code 5 while inserting data into sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have an application using sqlite where I'm checking if a particular record exists in table. If not, I am inserting data into table but while inserting it is giving me error code 5.

This is my code

```
-(int)addPayOptions:(NSString*)owner:(NSString*)bank:(NSString*)number:(NSString*)scheme:(NSString*)type:(NSString*)expiryDate:(NSString*)name
{
    NSString *queryString=nil;
    NSString *dbPath = [DBManager getdbpath];
    int val =0;
    @try {
        queryString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM PAYTABLE WHERE NAME='%@'",name];
        if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            int resp_code =sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [queryString UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL);
            NSLog(@"%d",resp_code);

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [queryString UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    val=0;
                    return val;
                    sqlite3_reset(statement);
                }
                else
                {
                    BOOL checkinserted =[self insertPayOptions:owner :bank :number :0:scheme:type:expiryDate:name];
                    if (checkinserted)
                    {
                        val=1;
                        return val;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        val=0;
                        return val;
                    }
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }

        }
        sqlite3_close(database);

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
    }

    return val;
}



-(BOOL)insertPayOptions:(NSString*)owner:(NSString*)bank:(NSString*)number:(NSString*)defaultOption:(NSString*)scheme:(NSString*)type:(NSString*)expiryDate:(NSString*)name
{

    const char *dbpath = [dbPath UTF8String];
    BOOL check = '\0';
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
         NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into PAYTABLE (OWNER,BANK,NUMBER,DEFAULT_OPTION,SCHEME,TYPE,EXPIRYDATE,NAME) VALUES('%@','%@','%@','%d','%@','%@','%@','%@')",owner,bank,number,0,scheme,type,expiryDate,name];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [insertSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_step(statement));
            if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                check=YES;
            }
            else
            {
                check =NO;
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

    return check;
}
```

Comment: In your 'insertPayOptions' DB path is in app bundle. The DB can't be updated / add new entry as its ready only. If you need to update / add new entry the DB has to be stored in Documents directory.

Comment: HI,@user2071152 i have updated my code.But this is also not working

Comment: I hope your DB is in Documents folder rather than in application bundle file. In 'insertPayOptions' method again you are trying to open the DB you can use the same instance of earlier sqlite3_open. In 'addPayOptions' method you have used 'sqlite3_prepare_v2' statement twice you can check the response code using the variable.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest you adopt named parameters as illustrated in the "Methods Can Take Parameters" section, buried in the [Defining Classes chapter in the Programming with Objective-C guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW8).

Comment: Also, you might want consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which makes SQLite programming much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A value of 5 is `SQLITE_BUSY`, which means that the database is currently busy doing something else (e.g., that a prior SQLite call was not properly finalized and closed).

Perhaps coincidentally, this method is a perfect example of precisely the sort of programming error that would cause this `SQLITE_BUSY` error. In your code, if the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` statement succeeded, you will never get to your `sqlite3_finalize` or `sqlite3_close` statements because you  `return` before getting to those finalize/close calls. Thus, the next time you call this method, it will tell you that the database is busy (because the prior call was never finalized and closed).

Be very, very wary of calling `return` inside your methods that perform SQLite calls, or if you do do employ `return` within the method, ensure that you call the appropriate `sqlite3_finalize` and `sqlite3_close` calls *before* returning. Or, better, refactor your code to minimize these `return` statements littered throughout the method, and it will be harder to make this mistake.

By the way, while this method conveniently illustrates the sort of programming error that would cause `SQLITE_BUSY`, it's not necessarily the case that this is the only situation in your code where you fail to finalize your statement or fail to close the database. You really should go through all of your SQLite related functions and consider each path of execution, and make sure that there's no possible way that `sqlite3_finalize` and `sqlite3_close` might fail to be called.

A couple of unrelated observations:

1. By the way, if a database call ever fails, it's often useful to log `sqlite3_errmsg`, which will be a little more informative regarding the precise nature of the error. For example, right now, if the prepare statement failed, you're silently returning, without any useful diagnostic information regarding any potential error.
2. You should avoid using `try`/`catch` blocks in Objective-C. While this is an important construct in other programming languages, in Objective-C you should do all of your error handling by looking at return codes (and where provided, examining `NSError` objects). In fact, since your `catch` block does nothing, you'll actually be obscuring any exceptions that take place, so it's even worse.
3. You should be very wary about using `stringWithFormat` to build your SQL statements. If the value included an apostrophe, your SQL would fail. Use `sqlite3_bind_text` instead, in conjunction with SQL that uses the `?` placeholder.
4. The use of `sqlite3_reset` statement is unnecessary in this case. You only use `sqlite3_reset` when reusing a previously prepared `sqlite3_stmt`, which you are not doing here. You called `sqlite3_reset` after your `return` statement, so perhaps this is academic, but nonetheless, this `sqlite3_reset` call can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi following code works for me you can check,

```
 NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM PAYTABLE WHERE NAME='%@'",name]];

                     int rows;
                     const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

                     if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                     {
                         sqlite3_step(statement);
                         rows = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

                         sqlite3_finalize(statement);

                         sqlStatement = "insert into PAYTABLE (OWNER,BANK,NUMBER,DEFAULT_OPTION,SCHEME,TYPE,EXPIRYDATE,NAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                         sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

                         if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(billDeskDB, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                         {

                                 sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [owner UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                                 sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, [bank UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                                 sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 3, [number UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                                 sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 4, [@"0" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                                 sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 5, [scheme UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                                 sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 6, [type UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                                 sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 7, [expiryDate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                                 sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 8, [name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                             }
                      }
```